# POST request on iOS - not working

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, post, facebook-ios-sdk

I have an iOS application which connects via OAuth 2.0 to Facebook. I would like to make a POST request which achieves the equivalent of this code in iOS:

```
curl -F 'access_token=...' \
 -F 'message=Hello. I like this new API.' \
 https://graph.facebook.com/[USER_ID]/feed
```

I found a nice tutorial online and I followed all the instructions, but I still can get my POST request to work. Here is my code:

```
    NSString *post = post_text.text;
    NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

    //NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];

    NSString *ready_post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/1313573269/feed?message=%@&access_token=CAACEdEose0cBAHgdZAon2EZBZCzjoLkhg7jrqvZAbliuoOQ2E2Exc4rZCAxPzeVEADwnQaNLYuG16Gq6q6LLLLLLLLVQ7LZAncXCc53qE2iyzleZAPXGajsgjnBTuo6YdJCZAxVGIYYD8sZCgQ9ypZCo0iOZBNuyrechBfee2yptlK9tmgdosZA7wrKg8ZD", postData];

    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:ready_post]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];
```

As you can see I am hard coding the access token for the time being just as a test. But I cant seem to get my app to actually POST anything to Facebook.

Thanks, Dan.

Comment: Whose id is `1313573269`?

Comment: That ID is mine. Obviously I won't hard code that either. But for the time being I am using it for a test. I have already got my application to authenticate with Facebook properly. So that ID should not be an issue here.

Comment: @Shadowfax Am I doing this POST request properly? I'm a little bit lost here.

Comment: @Shadowfax Do you know what I am doing wrong? Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: BTW, you probably don't want to post your access token in public like this, it allows anyone (along with your id, which you also posted) to post to facebook as if they're you.

Comment: @MingLi I didn't. My the access token displayed has been edited by myself, the access token above is pure rubbish. And as for the ID, anyone can figure out anyone's Facebook ID by going to graph.facebook.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to post a `JSON` to the GraphAPI - which you can't do.

Instead of that, you have to use parameters when posting (`query string` or `HTTP request parameters`).

See: [Publish to Feed](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/publish-to-feed-ios-sdk/).